# What means this 'F' before version?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

In some libraries of my app i have this "f=>x.x.x " in package.json

what f means?

`"engines": {`
`"node": "f>=14.15.x <17.0.0"`
`},`

some errors are occurred  when i run npm install like:

`npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {`

`npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@privaterepo/pub-sub-test@0.3.3',`

`npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: 'f>=14.15.x <17.0.0' },`

`npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.2', npm: '8.1.2' }`

`npm WARN EBADENGINE }`

update and downgrade lib
npm-check-updates
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

no one helped

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo? I don't think the `f` should be there...

Comment: im not sure, its next of "main" key in package.json
"main":"index.js",
"engines": {
        "node": "f>=14.15.x <15.0.0"
},

Comment: What package is this in?

Comment: its in our private repos

Comment: Well, you should probably look at whoever committed that `f` then and ask them.